# Как сделать два списка из одного в Python 3?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Есть список main_list, содержащий количество элементов n, причём 1<=n<=10 и два пустых списка list1 и list2.
Каждый элемент списка main_list содержит два числа a и b, идущих подряд через один пробел, причём 1<=a<=100 и 1<=b<=100. Нужно из каждого элемента списка main_list извлечь значение a и добавить в список list1, а значение b - в список list2.
Допустим,

```
main_list==['3 5', '1 2', '1 7']
```

Нужно получить `list1==[3,1,1]` и `list2==[5,2,7]`
Я пытался сделать так:

```
#создаём список main_list
main_list=['3 5', '1 2', '1 7']
#создаём списки list1 и list2
list1=list2=[]
for i in range(0,len(main_list)):
    #добавляем новый элемент в list1
    list1.append('')
    #добавляем новый элемент в list2
    list2.append('')
    #из i-го элемента списка main_list создаём список
    modification_list=list(main_list[i])
    #создаём индекс-счётчик для этого списка
    a=0
    #читаем цифры до пробела и заносим их
    #в i-й элемент (он же недавно добавленный) списка list1
    while modification_list[a]!=' ':
        list1[i]=modification_list[a]
        a=a+1
    #перешагиваем через пробел
    a=a+1
    #читаем цифры от пробела до конца и заносим их
    #в i-й элемент (он же недавно добавленный) списка list2
    for b in range(a, len(modification_list)):
    list2[i]=modification_list[b]
#преобразуем полученные данные из строкового типа в целочисленный
list1[i]=int(list1[i])
list2[i]=int(list2[i])
#выводим значения на экран
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Но, после выполнения программы получил вот что:

```
>>>
[5, 2, 7, '', '', '']
[5, 2, 7, '', '', '']
```

Помогите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код пока не читал, но сразу видно, что если условия и требуемый результат указаны полностью, то он очень-очень сильно перемудрён. Все можно сжать в одну-две строчки:

```
args = ([int(y) for y in x.split()] for x in main_list)
list1, list2 = zip(*args)
```

Суть такова: функция `zip` [сливает парами списки](http://ninjaside.info/blog/ru/funkcii-map-i-zip-i-lambda-python/), принимаемые ей в качестве аргумента, а подготавливаем мы эти аргументы с помощью двух вложенных друг в друга [генераторных выражений](http://whitepythons.blogspot.ru/2014/04/blog-post_27.html): внешний перебирает элементы `main_list`, внутренний разбирает строку на числа.

(В коде есть ошибки, по которым видно непонимание сути питона; распишу их позже (в комментарии на них указали как раз))

---

Суть ошибки с `list1=list2=[]` такова. `[]` — это список, список — это изменяемый объект. В этом выражении он создаётся один раз и присваивается в две переменные list1 и list2. В результате обе переменные указывают на один и тот же список, и при вызове append, соответственно, добавляемые элементы попадают в один и тот же список независимо от того, list1 или list2:

```
>>> list1=list2=[]
>>> list1.append(4)
>>> list2
[4]
>>> list1 is list2
True
```

Для чисел, строк и других примитивных типов (а также кортежей, но не совсем) ничего такого нет: это неизменяемые типы, объекты этих типов нельзя изменять (вы таких функций в питоне просто не найдёте), можно только записать другие объекты в переменную. Приведённый выше пример тоже можно переделать на создание нового списка несколькими способами, например, так:

```
>>> list1=list2=[]
>>> list1 = list1 + [4]  # сложение списков даёт новый независимый список
>>> list2
[]
>>> list1
[4]
>>> list1 is list2
False
```

Но лучше сразу создать раздельные списки и не мудрить:

```
>>> list1 = []; list2 = []
>>> list1 == list2
True
>>> list1 is list2
False
```

Comment: я две ощибки поравил, оно заработало.  `list1=[]   list2=[]` и `modification_list=main_list[i]`

Comment: Почему двум и более переменным можно присваивать одно и то же значение одновременно, например, так: `a=b=c=0`, а то же самое со списками и кортежами делать нельзя?

Comment: Дописал в ответ

Answer (score 0):

это конечно, не питонный код, а такой сишный на нем :))), но теперь он правильно работает

```
main_list=['32 5', '1 2', '1 7']
#создаём списки list1 и list2
list1=[]
list2=[]
for i in range(0,len(main_list)):
    #из i-го элемента списка main_list создаём список
    modification_list=main_list[i]
    #создаём индекс-счётчик для этого списка
    a=0
    #читаем цифры до пробела и заносим их
    #в i-й элемент списка list1
    while modification_list[a]!=' ':
        a=a+1
    list1.append(modification_list[:a])
    #перешагиваем через пробел
    # может, стоит раскоментировать следующую строку
    # while modification_list[a] == ' ':
    a=a+1
    #читаем цифры от пробела до конца и заносим их
    #в i-й элемент списка list2
    list2.append(modification_list[a:])
#преобразуем полученные данные из строкового типа в целочисленный
list1 = list(map(int, list1))
list2 = list(map(int, list2))
#выводим значения на экран
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> main_list=['3 5', '1 2', '1 7']
>>> list1 = [int(k) for k,j in [i.split() for i in main_list]]
>>> list1
[3, 1, 1]
>>> list2 = [int(j) for k,j in [i.split() for i in main_list]]
>>> list2
[5, 2, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = ["1 2", "22 33", "44 11"]
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> [[a.append(ll.split()[0]), b.append(ll.split()[1])] for ll in l]
>>> a
['1', '22', '44']
>>> b
['2', '33', '11']
```